# cakephp 4 find method with contain is skipping some records from subtable

Tags: relationship, contains, cakephp-4.x

I have master table `portfolios` and there are 2 child tables `portfoliotags` and `p_snaps`
models are as below

```
class PortfoliosTable extends Table
{ 
  public function initialize(array $config): void
  {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('portfolios');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->hasMany('PSnaps', [
        'foreignKey' => 'portfolio_id',
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('PortfolioTags', [
        'foreignKey' => 'portfolio_id',
    ]);
  }
}

class PortfolioTagsTable extends Table
{
  public function initialize(array $config): void
  {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('portfolio_tags');
    $this->setDisplayField('id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Portfolios', [
        'foreignKey' => 'portfolio_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Tags', [
        'foreignKey' => 'tag_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
  }
}

class PSnapsTable extends Table
{
  public function initialize(array $config): void
  {
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('p_snaps');
    $this->setDisplayField('title');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Portfolios', [
        'foreignKey' => 'portfolio_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
  }
}
```

`find()` method in controller is as below

```
$pfolios = $this->Portfolios->find('all')
        ->select(['Portfolios.id','Portfolios.client','Portfolios.country','Portfolios.url'])
        ->where(['Portfolios.status'=>1])
        ->order(['Portfolios.order_at'=>'asc','Portfolios.id'=>'asc'])
        ->limit(8)
        ->contain([
            'PSnaps'=>function($q){
                return $q
                    ->select(['PSnaps.portfolio_id','PSnaps.snap'])
                    ->where(['PSnaps.status'=>1])
                    ->order(['PSnaps.order_at'])
                    ->limit(1);
            },
            'PortfolioTags.Tags'=>function($q2){
                return $q2
                    ->order(['Tags.tag']);
            }
        ])
        ->toList(); 
    debug($pfolios);exit;
```

It is retuning PSnaps inside first record of Portfolio, while in all other records it is empty array
while I know there are records in database I tried using below query in mysql too

```
SELECT p.id,s.snap FROM `portfolios` p INNER join p_snaps s on p.id=s.portfolio_id
```

it is returning  records as below
**id  snap**
1   s1.png
2   pers.png
3   gmap.png
4   ita.png
5   soapd.png
6   chat.png
7   aissmo.png
8   zippy.png
2   pereport.png

Answer (score 0):

This is because of `limit()` inside `PSnaps`, if it is commented it will show all PSnap records under each Portfolios records.

To handle this situation I fix it by adding `hasOne` relation in `PortfoliosTable.php` as

```
$this->hasOne('FirstPSnaps', [
        'className' => 'PSnaps',
        'foreignKey' => 'portfolio_id',
        'strategy' => 'select',
        'sort' => ['FirstPSnaps.order_at' => 'ASC'],
        'conditions' => function ($e, $query) {
            return [];
        }]);
```

now call in controller will be changed to as below

```
$pfolios = $this->Portfolios->find('all')
        ->select(['Portfolios.id','Portfolios.client','Portfolios.country','Portfolios.url'])
        ->where(['Portfolios.status'=>1])
        ->order(['Portfolios.order_at'=>'asc','Portfolios.id'=>'asc'])
        ->limit(8)
        ->contain([
  /********instead of PSnap I used FirstPSnaps *********/
            'FirstPSnaps'=>function($q){
                return $q
                    ->select(['FirstPSnaps.portfolio_id','FirstPSnaps.snap'])
                    ->where(['FirstPSnaps.status'=>1])
                    ->order(['FirstPSnaps.order_at']);
            },
            'PortfolioTags.Tags'=>function($q2){
                return $q2
                    ->order(['Tags.tag']);
            }
        ])
        ->toList(); 
    debug($pfolios);exit;
```